What drove Walter White's bad behavior towards his son and Hank in Breaking Bad Season 2, Episode 10 ("Over")?
In the episode "Over" from Season 2 of Breaking Bad, Walter White exhibits troubling behavior towards his son, Walter Jr. (Flynn), and his brother-in-law, Hank Schrader. Specifically, Walter pressures his son to drink excessive amounts of alcohol during a family gathering, resulting in Walter Jr. vomiting in the pool. Additionally, Walter displays irritation towards Hank, who is a close relative and friend. I’m unsure what Hank did to provoke Walter's rude behavior towards him.
What psychological and emotional factors contribute to Walter's actions in this episode? How do these behaviors reflect his internal struggles and the dynamics of his relationships with his family? I’m looking for insights into Walter's character development and the implications of his actions in this context.
